# How do I make these divs scroll over top of the background img, when the main page is scrolled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a forum with banner divs -- lside banner, which spans the the left side of the forum, rside banner, which spans the right side, and tside banner, which sits at the top. The forum content is free-scrolling from lside and rside, which are static images, and the tside banner sits on the top and moves with the forum.

My issue is that I have 2 divs that sit over the rside banner. I would like them to scroll as well when the user scrolls, because as it stands right now, the 2nd div's content is hidden if your screen isn't big enough.

Here's what I've got:

```
     <div id="rside_content" style="overflow:hidden; position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; width: 20%;">
    <div id="rside_scroll_fix" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow:fixed;padding-right: 17px;">
```

So this should theoretically make that work, right? I can't figure out why it isn't working. So I started directly editting the 2nd div to see if it was the offender, but that didn't work either.

It was working before, it only recently stopped working, so it's clearly something I did. Perhaps when I added the tside banner it decided it couldn't work anymore but it doesn't have any interfering code as far as I can tell.

Anyone got any fixes or see anything wrong?